OSMnx geocode_to_gdf does not find ways and nodes by ID
Using OSMnx Library in Python, extracted a big geodataframe, with a lot of IDs in it.
From that GeoDataFrame i took some IDs, for example, an element with id: 263515466 with a "Way" type.
If I check the OpenStreetMap website, I can find this object - https://www.openstreetmap.org/way/263515466
But when I try to use the method, to determine some specific information, for example, using the geocode_to_gdf function, the code:
ox.geocoder.geocode_to_gdf('W263515466', which_result=None, by_osmid=True)

The full code, after installing all the packages:
import osmnx as ox

ox.geocoder.geocode_to_gdf('W263515466', which_result=None, by_osmid=True)

I get an error:
Error

Error Text:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InsufficientResponseError                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[534], line 1
----> 1 ox.geocoder.geocode_to_gdf('W263515466', which_result=None, by_osmid=True)

File ~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\osmnx\geocoder.py:139, in geocode_to_gdf(query, which_result, by_osmid, buffer_dist)
    137 gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame()
    138 for q, wr in zip(query, which_result):
--> 139     gdf = pd.concat([gdf, _geocode_query_to_gdf(q, wr, by_osmid)])
    141 # reset GeoDataFrame index and set its CRS
    142 gdf = gdf.reset_index(drop=True)

File ~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\osmnx\geocoder.py:186, in _geocode_query_to_gdf(query, which_result, by_osmid)
    183 if not results:
    184     # if no results were returned, raise error
    185     msg = f"Nominatim geocoder returned 0 results for query {query!r}"
--> 186     raise InsufficientResponseError(msg)
    188 if by_osmid:
    189     # if searching by OSM ID, always take the first (ie, only) result
    190     result = results[0]

InsufficientResponseError: Nominatim geocoder returned 0 results for query 'W263515466'


Why does this behave like this??
I was expecting to get a GDF on the ID, that I was watching for.

Per the OSMnx docs, the geocoder module uses the Nominatim API to geocode your queries. Features that exist in the OSM database occasionally do not exist in the Nominatim API under certain conditions.
Instead, you can use the features module to query for features at this location with tags matching something like "power=substation" and you'll find your way.
